# Only partial content is extract from table?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to extract content from a table however I'am only getting partial content.

I have entered the correct web element but instead of extracting data from 200(approx.) countries, i only get 6 countries.

The table seems to be java generated with scroll down feature, problem might have to do with that.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/users/usr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")

ExportsURL=driver.get("https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/WL D/Year/LTST/TradeFlow/Import/Partner/by-country/Show/MPRT-TRD-VL;MPRT-PRTNR-SHR;/Sort/Import%20(US$%20Thousand)") 

Countries =driver.find_element_by_id('contenttablejqx-PartnerGrid')
print(Countries.text)
```

Comment: Did you tried to scroll?

Comment: Yes i included a 5 sec wait and then scrolled down before  the' find element ' code line was effected however same output. Any advise?